# Create a Blinking and Colour Changing TextView

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-animation

I am creating a basic application where I have a few EditText fields and TextView fields.  I am wanting to create an activity where if I type 'yes' in the EditText field `TFusername`, I want the EditText field containing the word 'yes' to blink several times and also change to green in colour which can be either the text itself or the EditText field box.  Can someone help me on how the .java code should be written out for this processs?

I have attached the .xml code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bVoice"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:id="@+id/lvVoiceReturn"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/TFusername"
    android:hint="type here"
    android:textColor="#FF7A7A7A"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/caption_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Speak"
    android:id="@+id/bVoice"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick_1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Blogin"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Blogin"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Blogin" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/Blogin"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/result_text"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/result_text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText72"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:text="Test Application"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TFusername"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="67dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText73"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText72"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/result_text"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="YES"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText75"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText72"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText73"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText73"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="NO"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
anim.setDuration(50); //You can manage the blinking time with this parameter
anim.setStartOffset(20);
anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // if you want to change color at start of animation
                //textview.settextcolor("your color")
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // if you want to change color at end of animation
                //textview.settextcolor("your color")
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {


            }
        });
myText.startAnimation(anim);
```

Use setAnimationListener callback to change color of text in text view.

Comment: do you know where exactly this should be placed in the java file and when to refer to the `editText` ID?

Comment: Its up to your requirement where you want to add this function.
Like on click, on create, on resume ect.

Comment: okay, thanks I understand now. Do you know how I can also change the colour of the text whilst also blinking?

Comment: use settextcolor method of text view to set text.
If you want to change color while animation, you can call settextcolor method from callback you are getting animation listener.

Comment: thanks, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by implementing it in animation listener? Yes, I do want it to change colour while animating. Are you able to add to the above sample code you have added and then I'll accept the solution once working. thanks